# Cannot sort array into ascending order in Python

Tags: python, arrays, sorting

I know I could use the sort() function, but I am trying to do this without using that.

```
from random import randint
# Create variables
numberArray = [0]*20

# Populate array
for i in range(0,20):
    numberArray[i] = randint(0,300)

# Sort array into ascending order
print("Sorting array into ascending order...")

sortedAscending = False
while sortedAscending == False:
    for i in range(0,20):
        sortedAscending = True
        if i != (len(numberArray)-1):
            if numberArray[i] > numberArray[i+1]:
                temp = numberArray[i]
                numberArray[i] = numberArray[i+1]
                numberArray[i+1] = temp
                sortedAscending = False
                for j in range(0,20):
                    print(numberArray[j])
                print("END OF ARRAY")
                print()

for i in range(0,20):
    print(numberArray[i])
```

It starts sorting the array, but then fails to sort any numbers after a few loops. Please help.
Note: the loop with "END OF ARRAY" is for debugging.

Comment: (1) Show how it fails, don't just say that it fails. (2) StackOverflow's focus is on *practical* questions (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic); exercises are... not ideal.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, "it doesn't work".  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Comment: (This is... a bubble sort, I think? You might edit the title to say you're trying to implement a bubble sort, so people who want to help with practical problems can see that and go elsewhere, rather than clicking through and being annoyed).

Comment: Note: this is not an array, it is a *list*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this and let me know if it works :) (I've tested it 2-3 times so far it has been working well)

```
from random import randint
# Create variables
numberArray = [0]*20

# Populate array
for i in range(0,20):
    numberArray[i] = randint(0,300)
# Sort array into ascending order
print("Sorting array into ascending order...")

sortedAscending = False
while sortedAscending == False:
    sortedAscending = True # this should be before the for loop
    for i in range(0,20):
        if i != (len(numberArray)-1):
            if numberArray[i] > numberArray[i+1]:
                temp = numberArray[i]
                numberArray[i] = numberArray[i+1]
                numberArray[i+1] = temp
                sortedAscending = False
                for j in range(0,20):
                    print(numberArray[j])
                print("END OF ARRAY")
                print()

for i in range(0,20):
    print(numberArray[i])
```

I moved the `sortedAscending = True` out of the for loop

Answer (score 0):

You have implemented **bubble sort**.

In python swapping the values are pretty simple. Suppose you want to swap the values of numberArray[i] and numberArray[i+1] then
simply you can use this.

```
numberArray[i], numberArray[i+1] = numberArray[i+1], numberArray[i]
```

Here is your code. This code should work fine for you.

```
from random import randint
# Create variables
numberArray = [0]*20

# Populate array
for i in range(0,20):
    numberArray[i] = randint(0,300)
# Sort array into ascending order
print("Sorting array into ascending order...")

sortedAscending = False
while sortedAscending == False:
    sortedAscending = True # this should be before the for loop
    for i in range(0,20):
        if i != (len(numberArray)-1):
            if numberArray[i] > numberArray[i+1]:
                 numberArray[i], numberArray[i+1] = numberArray[i+1], numberArray[i]
                 sortedAscending = False
for i in range(0,20):
    print(numberArray[i])
```